# Not able to deploy .Net6 app to new azure app services

Tags: azure, azure-web-app-service, .net-6.0

I have triggered the pipeline in Azure . It is successfully triggered. No issues found. But when checked the app service application url, It shows "This page can’t be found".
But in app service on Azure also , I am able to see that it is deployed successfully.

Can you all please highlight the workaround here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like the AzureRmWebAppDeployment@4 task got a new update (v4.205.13) that doesn't output variables like the AppServiceApplicationUrl.  It was working for us with v4.198.0.

See Issue https://github.com/microsoft/azure-pipelines-tasks/issues/16467

Comment: Thanks for the input. But I have checked with AzureRmWebAppDeployment@3. But observing the same issue. Can you please let me know that how to use the correct version?

Comment: See comments in the mentioned issue. @3 (v4.200.13) and @4 have similar issues. Users bypassed the issue by building their own URL:  [servicename].azurewebsites.net until a real fix is push...